# Resetear Form input:valid / input:invalid

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

quiero combinar la validacion de bootstap 5 y a la vez personalizarla con JS (DOM), el problema que tengo un formulario donde si apreto submit me marca en rojo los campos  requeridos, hasta ahi perfecto, el tema que si cierro ese formulario, al volver abrilo me sigue los campos en rojo, necesito que vuelva a su estado original (primera imagen) sin marcar, puedo modificar de alguna forma? tengo un reset del formulario que funciona correctamente, pero no resetea los input:invalid.El form lo tengo a su vez en una ventana modal. Intente por DOM modificar la pseudoclase input:invalid pero no pude, y si le agrego input:valid me lo marcaria en verde estando vacíos así que no me serviría.

[image: Estado A]

[image: Estado B]

Estuve leyendo la documentacion de bootstap pero en el inspector del navegador no veo que ponga ninguna clase valid ni invalid para doder quitárcela o modificarla.

```js
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')
//forms.querySelectorAll('input').classList.remove('invalid')


// Bucle sobre ellos y evitar el envío
Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
  .forEach(function (form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
      }

      form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
  })
```

```html
<div id="login">
          <form action="verificar.php" method="POST" id="FormLogin" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
              <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="nombre@ejemplo.com" name="usuario" required autofocus>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Por favor, ingrese su correo registrado.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
              <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" name="clave" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Por favor, ingrese su password.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3  row">
              <button class=" btn btn-primary" type="submit">Igresar</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <span>¿No tienes cuenta? <a class="text-decoration-none" href="#" onclick="loadFormRegistro()">Regístrate</a></span> <br>
          <span><a class="text-decoration-none" href="#" onclick="loadFormRecupero()">Recuperar password</a></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: El formulario está en una ventana modal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hasta donde yo conozco, hay 2 métodos con que bootstrap marca una validación con errores. El primero de forma global agregando la clase 'was-validated' al elemento form.  Y el otro es elemento a elemento agregando la clase 'is-invalid' a cada input/select/textarea/etc.

Te dejo una función para resetar un form

```js
function ResetForm(form) {
    form.classList.remove('was-validated');
    form.querySelectorAll(".is-invalid").forEach(el => el.classList.remove('is-invalid'));
    
    form.reset();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button onclick="ResetForm(document.getElementById('FormLogin'))">RESET!!</button>
<div id="login">

          <form action="verificar.php" method="POST" id="FormLogin"  class="needs-validation was-validated" novalidate>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
              <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="nombre@ejemplo.com" name="usuario" required autofocus>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Por favor, ingrese su correo registrado.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
              <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" name="clave" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Por favor, ingrese su password.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3  row">
              <button class=" btn btn-primary" type="submit">Igresar</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <span>¿No tienes cuenta? <a class="text-decoration-none" href="#" onclick="loadFormRegistro()">Regístrate</a></span> <br>
          <span><a class="text-decoration-none" href="#" onclick="loadFormRecupero()">Recuperar password</a></span>
        </div>
```